# Location based search on Android

Tags: android, search, google-maps

I'm trying to create an Android app that searches for a certain type of business near the user's current location. I found the Google Places API, but it doesn't look like you can specify what type of place you want to search for. They also say you're not allowed to filer the results, so I can't even just filter out the ones i'm actually looking for.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to search for nearby places of a certain type? This will eventually be displayed using the Google MapView for the Android. But the big problem I'm facing right now is how to get the list of businesses I'm looking for.

Thanks for any help you can give!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently I feel the service with the best crowdsourced business data is Yelp, and lo and behold, they have [an API](http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/search_api).  You can execute searches in a few different ways, including [narrowing by category](http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/search_api#narrowCat).

Comment: Thanks Neil. I'm looking into the Yelp API now. Reading through TOS and Display Requirements is always a pain... but so far it looks like this would work. Any other suggestions would be appreciated, always nice to have options.

Comment: Yelp looks like a good option. After a little bit of playing around with it, seems like it'll do what I want. Little worried about the daily limit of service calls, but seems like they're willing to increase it if needed. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score -1):

If you look at the [Places API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/#PlaceDetails), the results return an array of types, which include terms like "restaurant", "food", etc. Maybe you can filter on these terms.

Combine this with some reflective XML parsing on some plain objects and you'd have a pretty powerful system. I'd guess this is how the official Android Places app works.

Although Places isn't on this list, the [GData-java-client](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/) library can be used with Android. You can get some ideas for parsing and style from the examples there.

Comment: This is not a good solution. As mentioned in the question, I already know about the Places API, however the Terms of User prohibit filtering results returned by a Place search, and there doesn't appear to be any way to search by category.